# How to scroll to particular id in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Html code is

```html
<p id="4" style="color: red;">Dit antwoord is verplicht</p>
<p id="5" style="color: red;">Dit antwoord is verplicht</p>
```

i have add scrollIntoView but it's not working any other solution for scroll to particular id in react js

```js
 document.getElementById(4).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Try <a href=“#4”>scroll to id 4</a>

Comment: i am not using a tag i want set within function

Comment: You forget to add quotes in this  document.getElementById(“4”).scrollIntoView()

Comment: But some browsers doesn’t support it.

Comment: You could calculate the position of the item eg ID and scroll to it by Js, its very easy

Comment: can you send any example

Answer (score 1):

Here you can give try,

```
 window.scrollTo(0,this.findPosition(document.getElementById(4)));
```

Below function is for finding place of particular id.

```
 findPosition(obj) {
   var currenttop = 0; 
   if (obj.offsetParent) { 
      do { 
          currenttop += obj.offsetTop;
       } while ((obj = obj.offsetParent)); 
      return [currenttop]; 
     } 
  }
```

Comment: should `while ((obj = obj.offsetParent)); ` use `==` ? So that we get ```obj == obj.offsetParent```